# How to avoid my VisualFoxPro' EXE File tobe disassembled

Tags: foxpro, disassembly

i have try refox and see how eazy my EXE to be disassembled. the refox offer a feature which they guarantee that no one can disassembled. but , is there any other alternative ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look at KONxiSE.

http://www.xitech-europe.co.uk/konxise.php

If you are accessing external VFP apps there might be a problem doing so, but I have heard good things about this tool.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the comments on the [VFP Wiki page on disassemblers](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~VfpDecompilers): even Refox Level 2 can apparently be bypassed.

Comment: so , it's useless to code in visual foxpro for commerical purpose ?

Comment: You can reverse engineer Java or C# code very easily - would you also say that nobody should use those for commercial development ?

Comment: You might want to look into obfuscating your code before release to make it harder on the person who decompiles it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a security wrapper? I have successfully used a product called MoleBox Pro to encrypt and compress my Visual FoxPro applications. However, I have had difficulties while attempting to use the latest incarnation, MoleBox Ultra.

http://www.molebox.com

Trial downloads are available from the site. No harm in taking a look!